# Drupal 7 GetLocations field geocoding off?

Tags: google-maps

I am using this: https://www.drupal.org/project/getlocations

The problem is, when I add a geolocations field to a content type, and type in, for example:

```
Boulders Beach, Kleintuin Road, Cape Town, Western Cape
```

If I see maps.google.co.za, I get:

```
-34.197116,18.451423
```

But the geolocations field gives me:

```
-34.1964859,18.45004849999998
```

In this specific case the difference isn't that big, but I've had a few cases where it's completely wrong. For example:

```
Spier Wine Farm, Stellenbosch
```

Correct google result:

```
-33.973474,18.782544
```

what I get on the geolocations field:

```
-33.9805299, 18.773583700000017
```

It looks like they are off by 0.007, 0.009.

Any ideas why this could be happening?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The API geocoder may be different from the Maps geocoder (see the [FAQ in the API documentation](http://developers.google.com/maps/faq#geocoder_differences)). The results may even vary for users from different users from different countries. For me, `Spier Wine Farm, Stellenbosch` results on Google Maps in `-33.9733628,18.7825561`.

In general, it seems that sometimes providing less information in an address results in more exact coordinates, see this [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10826730/google-maps-api-v3-is-returning-the-wrong-location-coordinates) on s.o.

UPDATE: Interesting fact: the same address produces even different coordinates for different browsers. Coordinates stated above came from Google Chrome. When doing the same in Mozilla Firefox, I get `-33.973474,18.782544` (which is what you had in your question).